# How to create a specific frontend URL (not a Page) from a theme or plugin?

Tags: url-rewriting, ajax, urls

My theme implements an AJAX action that returns some dynamic content and needs some functions from the Wordpress environment. How can I construct a URL for the AJAX call in the most elegant and robust way?

In particular, I see lots of themes and plugins directly linking to PHP files that are inside their directory tree, which in turn are totally different entry points from Wordpress's `index.php`, and then include this:

```
// INCLUDE WORDPRESS STUFF
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
include_once('../../../wp-load.php');
```

From an architecture perspective, this does not seem elegant to me (we create another entry point to the app), and it also breaks if I want to symlink the theme directory to some place else.

I think WordPress doesn't implement a full-fledged router as the ones from typical Web frameworks, but is there a way to create specific (not custom posts, for instance) frontend URLs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [AJAX in Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins). Themes work the same way. So, you *get* an API, some gotchas inclusive. :)

Our tag [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) is quite popular too; you may find some good solutions there.

Comment: I had stumbled upon this article, but was unsure whether this was what I was looking for. I will read it in more detail and post my findings -- thanks!

Comment: It is what you're looking for.  Despite the `admin-ajax.php` file name, it works everywhere (assuming everything is hooked in correctly).

Comment: ...and not hidden behind some `if ( ! is_admin() )` conditional :P

Comment: Finally got to try it, and it answers my needs perfectly. Only thing that was not obvious (at least to me) in the doc page is that you should actually replace `my_action` in the hook name itself (`wp_ajax_my_action`) by your own string. For the sake of completeness with respect to the question, is there a way to create custom frontend URLs? Should I create a "fake page" and add a specific template file?

Comment: @julien_c Custom URLs aren’t so hard. I recommend [A (Mostly) Complete Guide to the WordPress Rewrite API](http://pmg.co/a-mostly-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-rewrite-api) as a start.